# GCC: template previously defined error

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, g++

I have the following code that is working with Visual C++ 10 but not with GCC on linux:

```
class basic_format 
{
    ... 
    basic_format() : str_(), fmt_() {}
    ... 

    template <class ValueT>
    basic_format& operator%(const ValueT& x) 
    {
    ...
    }

    template <class Ch, class Tr>
    friend std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(
        std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& sout, const basic_format<Ch, Tr>& f) 
    {
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Use:

```
query << basic_format<char_type>("%s %s HTTP/%.1f\r\n") % method % path % this->version();
```

The compiler yells:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - ‘template<class Ch, class Tr> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& clx::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const clx::basic_format<Ch, 
     Tr>&)’ previously defined here
    - redefinition of ‘template<class Ch, class Tr> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& clx::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const 
     clx::basic_format<Ch, Tr>&)’
```

I am using GCC 4.4.7
Can I do something to avoid this error on GCC ?

Comment: Explain in detail what are you trying to do. Where is declaration of operator, inside other class or not? What is the purpose of this code - to friend some existing operator or define new friend operator or maybe replace existing operator?

Comment: @user2807083 this two definitions are in the same class. I use this two templates to format the HTTP request like shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.9.3, compiles and works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Ch = char, class Tr = std::char_traits<char>>
class basic_format
{
    template <class C, class T>
    friend std::basic_ostream<C, T>& operator<<(
            std::basic_ostream<C, T>& sout, const basic_format<C, T>& f)
    {
        return sout << "lol";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << basic_format<>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I am using GCC 4.4.7 I've tried your example alone and it works only if I enable: g++ -std=c++0x. Anyway doing the same on my project it dose not fix the error. Maybe has to do with the fact that in the same cpp it's defined another template with the same parameter-list ? I have added this in my original question.

Comment: @cristian that template has different name, so it's not the reason. Check the line that `previously defined here` points to. If it's not present in code, mabye an implicit instantiation of template occured and caused the error. If you can, post lines that error message mentions.

Comment: The only line that has the error is line 3 from my post ( marked with "<---ERROR" at the end ). I could not understand what line you want me to check :(

Comment: @cristian Error previously defined here should point to two lines, first definition and error-causing redefinition. Change your function signature a bit, like, add some spaces, so you can see the difference between two. simple example: `void fun(int a);` and `void fun  (   int a   );` You should see difference in error message.

Comment: Ohh.... now I understand. Thank you. I have identified the other definition and added in the question. This two together causes the conflict. I don't get though way this isn't working on GCC...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the def of the second template outside the class without "friend" and keep only the declaration inside:

```
class basic_format 
{
    basic_format() : str_(), fmt_() {}

    template <class ValueT>
    basic_format& operator%(const ValueT& x) 
    {
    ...
    }

    template <class Ch, class Tr>
    friend std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(
        std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& sout, const basic_format<Ch, Tr>& f);
}

template <class Ch, class Tr>
std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& sout, const basic_format<Ch, Tr>& f) 
{
  ...
}
```